# Android Actionbar - How to remove extra padding added in Support Library v24?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-support-library

I'm using a preference activity (AppCompatPreferenceActivity specifically from AOSP) and having a problem with the new padding added in the Support V24 library.

The way to remove the padding on a toolbar is to use this line

```
app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
```

I'm unable to use a toolbar though in the the preference activity since we're using preference headers, and when you get into nested preferences there are some really bizarre problems that pop up with the toolbar.  I'd really rather not go back to a toolbar as all the fixes were hacky and still weren't able to solve all problems.

Does anyone know how to remove the padding on an actionbar?  The line to remove it on a toolbar is not valid on actionbar styles.